# BMO $2005$ Round$1$ Problem$2$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

[image: BMO 2005 Round1 Problem2]

I want to verify my solution for part $2$.

Let there be three teams A, B and C.
$\text{WLOG}$, for team A, start by choosing $1$ member out of $12$, $12\choose1$ then we cannot have twin of this member in the team so now remains $10$ members to choose from, we have $10\choose1$ ways then $8\choose1$ ways and at last $6\choose1$ ways.

$$\text{Team A:-} \hspace{0.5cm} \underline{12\choose1} \times \underline{10\choose1} \times \underline{8\choose1} \times \underline{6\choose1}$$

In team A one possible combination could be $(T_{11}, T_{21}, T_{31}, T_{41})$ but it is also possible to have $(T_{41}, T_{31}, T_{11}, T_{21})$ in the team. In other words, there are $4!$ ways to arrange $4$ things in ordered manner but we don't want the order. So,

$$\text{Team A:-} \hspace{0.5cm} \left[\; \underline{12\choose1} \times \underline{10\choose1} \times \underline{8\choose1} \times \underline{6\choose1} \; \right] \div 4!$$

For team B, we have $8$ members where we have $2$ pairs of twins and $4$ twins of already selected members.
Check that we cannot do $\underline{8\choose1} \times \underline{6\choose1} \times \underline{4\choose1} \times \underline{2\choose1}$ to select the members. If we did this then we can have team which includes the twins. So we must separate out the twins. We can do this by choosing $1$ member out of $2$ pairs of twins and then $1$ member out of the other pair of twin. Now two empty spots are left and we can fill them by choosing $2$ members out of remaining $4$.

$$\text{Team B:-} \hspace{0.5cm} \underline{4\choose1} \times \underline{2\choose1} \times \underline{4\choose2}$$

If you check it, then again we counted extras but this time only twice as many. So,

$$\text{Team B:-} \hspace{0.5cm} \left[\; \underline{4\choose1} \times \underline{2\choose1} \times \underline{4\choose2} \; \right] \div 2!$$

Team C will be made automatically

We got $$\frac{{12\choose1}  {10\choose1} {8\choose1} {6\choose1}}{4!} \times \frac{{4\choose1}{2\choose1}{4\choose2}}{2!} = 5760$$

Why multiply? Because for each combination of team B we got one combination of team A.
But wait a minute the order of the team doesn't matter either so there should really be $\frac{5760}{3!} \text{ways} = 960$

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is solid and correct. A recommended way to check a combinatoric solution is by coming up with an alternative method that yields the same result. Here's one:

$$
\frac{2^{6}}{3!}\cdot\binom{6}{2,2,2}=960
$$

**Explanation**

Each twin pair go to two different teams. Assign labels $AB$, $BC$, and $AC$ based on the two teams that the twin pair go to. Since the teams have the same number of members, there must be two twins for each label and there are $\binom{6}{2,2,2}$ possibilities.

After assigning the labels, we divide by the order of three teams, i.e. $3!$, since the teams are unordered.

Last, each twin have two possibilities, e.g., first kid go to team A the second kid go to team B or the other way around. There are $6$ twin pairs, so multiply with $2^{6}$.

Comment: What does ${6\choose{2,2,2}}$ represent here? I think this is multinomial but I didn’t understand the meaning of it.

Comment: @user1150809 multinomial is $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$, it's the number of possibilities to choose two out of six for a group, another two from the remaining to another group, and the remaining two to the last group

Comment: So it’s equivalent to ${6\choose2}{4\choose2}$?

Comment: @user1150809 yes, exactly.

Comment: I think I am good with my solution. Like sometimes I am getting it and sometimes it just doesn’t make sense. I know your numbers are correct (there is a video on BMO with same solution) but they aren’t making sense to me right now. Also this problem’s solution took me 3 hours so I think I should stop here only. I will try to think upon it some other time. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is okay.

Alternative:

Pick out some twin and set the $2$ persons apart in the sense that they are members/representants of $2$ different teams. For filling up one of those teams with $3$ persons we first select $3$ of the $5$ remaining twins and then from each of these twins we select $1$ person. So there are $\binom53\times 2^3=80$ ways to do that.

Now we aim to fill up the other team with $3$ persons and there are $2$ twins and $3$ singles to choose from. We *must* select $1$ person from each of the twins (to make sure that the twins do not end up in the same team) and to complete we must choose one of $3$ singles. So there are $2^2×3=12$ ways to do that.

Then automatically $4$ unselected persons remain that form the third team, so finally we arrive at $80\times12\times1=960$ possibilities.